# Angular material: mat-error not showing despite true methods

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a confirm password formcontrol that I want to validate.

I want to display my mat-error element when the password is not the same as the value in the confirm password input. For this I have a function called `equalPasswords()`. If the functions are the same then we receive true, if not, we receive false.

```
<mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Repeat password" [formControl]="password2" type="password">
              <mat-error *ngIf="password2.invalid && password2.hasError('required')">Password is required</mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="!equalPasswords() && !password2.hasError('required')">Passwords need to match</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I checked the console and when I enter two different inputs in the password boxes it equalPasswords() returns false. It however still doesn't show the error in the DOM.

Does someone know how to fix this?

**Signup.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-sign-up',
    templateUrl: 'sign-up.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['sign-up.component.css']
})

export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

    mySignupForm: FormGroup;
    countries = countries;
    uniqueUsernameMessage;
    uniqueEmailMessage;
    formSubmitted = false;
    @Output() closeSubmenu = new EventEmitter();
    @ViewChild('select') select;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private route: Router,
        private navigationService: NavigationService){}

    get firstName() { return this.mySignupForm.get('firstName'); }
    get lastName() { return this.mySignupForm.get('lastName'); }
    get username() { return this.mySignupForm.get('username'); }
    get email() { return this.mySignupForm.get('email'); }
    get password1() { return this.mySignupForm.get('password1'); }
    get password2() { return this.mySignupForm.get('password2'); }
    get birthDate() { return this.mySignupForm.get('birthDate'); }
    get country() { return this.mySignupForm.get('country'); }
    get house() { return this.mySignupForm.get('house'); }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mySignupForm = new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            username: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(15)]),
            birthDate: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            password1: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15), Validators.pattern('^.*(?=.{4,10})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$')]),
            password2: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
            country: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            house: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        })
    }

    equalPasswords() {

        console.log('equaltest', this.password1.value === this.password2.value);
        return this.password1.value === this.password2.value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`MatFormField` only displays `mat-error` elements when the `FormControl` has an error. It does not display just because you tell it to via `ngIfElse` - that would only work subject to the form control state. One way to solve this problem is to create a custom validator and use it to check that the passwords match. You could also set an error on the field from your `equalPasswords()` function. That should be something like:

```
equalPasswords(): boolean {

    const matched: boolean = this.password1.value === this.password2.value;

    console.log('equaltest', matched);

    if (matched) {
        this.signupForm.controls.password2.setErrors(null);
    } else {
        this.signupForm.controls.password2.setErrors({
           notMatched: true
        });
    }

    return matched;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I discovered asubtle situation where this can occur.

If you add a `[formGroup]` *directive* on something like a `<div>` then it will not get `submitted == true` when the form is submitted (it must be on a `<form>` for that to occur).

The form being submitted is one of two triggers for displaying the error - the other is for the field to have been touched. And touched means `onBlur` which means the focus must have been **lost**.

So you can get this situation:

- You have `[formGroup]` on a div
- You have something like a username / password form.
- You also have a submit button.
- You enter both fields and hit enter.
- **Your validation triggers an error but it doesn't show! WHY!**
- Because you never `blur`-ed the password field (take a look at your cursor - it's still in the password field isn't it!)
- The easiest solution is to only ever add `[formGroup]` to a `<form>` tag
- The other is to create a custom [`ErrorStateMatcher`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/input-error-state-matcher/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts)

If you are passing a `formGroup` to a 'dumb' child component via an @Input (that is to a dumb component that doesn't manage its own form) you can use dependency injection and pass in the `FormGroupDirective` instead in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the G. Tranter comment, to see the mat-error element, the form field have to be touched.
You can force it with the line

```
this.myForm.get('password2').markAsTouched();
```