# How to create custom input error in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, materialize, angular-material2

I'm trying to create my own validator for angular material input... i want to check that only letters, numbers and spaces are valid... I've created a custom void that check this, but i can't get this to work...
This is my code:

```
<md-input-container class="full-width" >
  <input name="nombre" required [(ngModel)]="name" mdInput placeholder="Nombre">
  <md-error *ngIf="checkSpecialCharacters()">Se han ingresado caracteres invalidos</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

and the TS

```
valid = true;
public name: string;
checkSpecialCharacters () {
  this.valid = true;
  if (this.name.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.name.length; i++) {
      if (this.name.charAt(i).match(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/) !== null) {
        this.valid = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return this.valid;
}
```

which statement should i use? or how? Thanks

(this is a spanish app, that's why there is some spanish words)

Comment: Check out the [angular docs on writing custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) and see if that points you in a good direction. This is something outside of material and within the scope of the angular forms framework.

Answer (score 0):

I second @p4r1's comment. This is in the scope of the angular forms frame work. I can show you how i have been creating custom validation in my uses.

It'd be easier to handle if we use form instead of ngModel. I assume your work doesn't require template driven models.

in your TS file:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', checkSpecialCharacters().bind(this))
});

checkSpecialCharacters(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (control.value.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < control.value.length; i++) {
        if (control.value.charAt(i).match(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/) !== null) {
          return {'error': {value: control.value}};
        }
      }
     }
    };
  }
```

and in your HTML:

instead if ngmodel use formControlName= name and in your *ngIf use *ngIf="name.error" , i.e:

```
 <md-error *ngIf="name.error">Se han ingresado caracteres invalidos</md-error>
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `<mat-error>` element will only be displayed when the input control's state is error (See this post: [Angular material: mat-error not showing despite true methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480822/angular-material-mat-error-not-showing-despite-true-methods/52481761#52481761)). Things are a little more complicated when you use ngModel instead of formControl, but the principle is the same because ngModel uses a FormControl internally.

When using reactive forms and FormControl, the easiest thing to do would be to add a custom validator to your input's FormControl (and you could do that with ngModel also - but it's more work since you have to reference the FormControl via the ngModel which requires using ViewChild etc.).

The easiest way to do this with ngModel and Angular Material is to simply use a custom ErrorStateMatcher for the MatInput. This will take care of referencing the internal FormControl automatically. Take a look at https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown.

You would then call your checkSpecialCharacters function from inside your ErrorStateMatcher rather than from the mat-error ngIf:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

/** Error when invalid control is dirty, touched, or submitted. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    if (control && control.invalid 
        && (control.touched || (form && form.submitted))) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return !checkSpecialCharacters(control.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Updated component:

```
errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

checkSpecialCharacters(value: string): boolean {
  let valid = true;
  if (value && value.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.name.length; i++) {
      if (value.charAt(i).match(/^[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/) !== null) {
        valid = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return valid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="full-width" >
  <input name="nombre" required [(ngModel)]="name" mdInput placeholder="Nombre" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher">
  <md-error>Se han ingresado caracteres invalidos</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Note that this is based on my knowledge of Angular Material 6 - I believe it will be fine on v2 as well.